# Javascript Multistep Form with Validation

Tags: javascript, forms, multipage

I am trying to create a multistep form using javascript and div.  I know how to create the form this way but the problem is I want the fields in each step to be validated before moving to the next. Example: If the user did not fill up a required field or have error in a field the box will be highlighted in red and they will not be bring to the next step until it is corrected.  I know how to do validation but not able to stop the page.  Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: considered using any js framework like jQuery?

Comment: Do you have a next button you wish to disable until all the fields are valid, possibly with invalid fields marked immediately.  Or do you wish the validation to happen when a next button is pressed and no advance made?

Comment: source code or the answer's `purple`

Answer (score 0):

To stop the form from submitting you need to add

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="validate(); return false;">
```

Validate is your function for validationg, then you can call something like this

```
document.getElementById('form').submit()
```

if the form is valid ;)

Comment: Actually, `validate()` will never be called in this scenario -- `return false;` will either terminate the code right away or generate an error.  `validate(this)` should return `false` if the validation fails to stop the form from submitting.

Comment: One thing to note thou is you must actually have return false; in the onsubmit. "return validate()" won't run correctly in "some" browsers. So you need to "validate(); return false;"